# Resized partition to too small value after shrinking filesystem

Tags: partition, fsck, parted, resize2fs, e2fsck

I shrinked an `ext4` filesystem with `resize2fs`:

```
resize2fs -p /dev/sdn1 3500G
```

(FS is used for 2.3 TB)

Then I resized the partition with parted and left a 0.3% margin (~10 GB) when setting the new end:

```
(parted) resizepart 1 3681027097kb
```

Eventually, this turned out to be too tight:

```
# e2fsck -f /dev/sdn1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 917504000 blocks
The physical size of the device is 898688000 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
Abort<y>? yes
```

Then I resized the partition again, this time with 3% margin:

```
(parted) resizepart 1 3681027097kb
```

After this, filesystem checks pass:

```
# e2fsck -f /dev/sdn1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sdn1: 278040/114688000 files (12.4% non-contiguous), 608536948/917504000 blocks
```

I have run `partprobe /dev/sdn` after the two `resizepart` commands.

I haven't mounted the filesystem in the whole process (and not mounted it yet even).

May the intermediate step in which I resized the partition to a too small value have corrupted the fs?

Is the successful run of `e2fsck` enough to be sure that data has not been damaged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I resized the partition to a too small value have corrupted the fs?

It's unlikely in your case, especially since you were kind enough to stop that fs(c)killer, but you can't rule out the possibility entirely.

For example, corruption happens when it's a logical partition inside the extended partition of a msdos partition table. Logical partitions are linked lists, so between logical partitions there is a sector used to point to the next partition in the list. If you shrink/resize such a logical partition there is a sector (partially) overwritten somewhere in the middle of the disk.

Also some partitioner programs might enjoy zeroing things out. This is also the case with LVM, on each lvcreate it zeroes out like the first 4K of the created LV, and besides there is no guarantee that reversing a botched lvresize will give you the same extents back that were used before. If unlucky the LV might be located physically elsewhere, which is why you can only undo such accidents by `vgcfgrestore` something from `/etc/lvm/{backup,archive}/` that was created before the lvresize.

With SSDs there's this TRIM fad that causes all sorts of programs to issue unwarranted TRIM commands to the SSD. LVM does this if `issue_discards=1` in lvm.conf (always set it to 0), here's to hoping that the various partitioning programs will never adopt this behaviour.

> Is the successful run of e2fsck enough to be sure that data has not been damaged?

Most filesystems are not able to detect data corruption outside of their own metadata. Which is usually not a problem since you're not supposed to pull stunts like these. If you have a backup you could compare file timestamps / checksums with what you have in your backups.

> I haven't mounted the filesystem in the whole process (and not mounted it yet even).

You can mount it read-only like so:

```
mount -o loop,ro /dev/sdn1 /mnt/somewhere
```

and then check out the files.

The `loop,ro` tells mount to create a read-only loop device and mount that. Surprisingly, `ro` by itself does not guarantee readonlyness for some filesystems including `ext4`. (And for multiple-device filesystems like `btrfs`, the `loop,ro` doesn't either because it affects only one device, not all of them).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed analysis. Data was not corrupted indeed :)